# jQuery focus() doesn't take the cursor into the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I know that `$('#siteTitle').focus()` takes the focus into the input field which has the id `siteTitle`, and I also know that `focus()` causes the input to become the current active element of the document, thus retrievable via `document.activeElement`.
My problem is that, I can't type anything into `titleInput` field in spite of setting focus on it. My input has some formatting already applied on it, and has a default dimmed watermark:

[image]

But no cursor is shown inside it, and worse, I can't type in it. As I said, when I use `document.activeElement`, input field is returned. Therefore, I'm sure that it has focus.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="titleWrapper">
        <div class="titleInpWrapper">
            <input type="text" name="title" id="titleInput" value="Site Name" tabindex='0' /></div>
        <p class="label">
           What's your site's name?</p>
        <p class='alert titleStep'>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the `input` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think another javascript piece of code is interfering with your typing. Check that.

You can use firefox's fireQuery add-on to see if the element has other events binded to it

Comment: Yeah, that was right. I had another `div` element with `tabindex` of the same as my input, and somewhere else, I was making that element the active element of document, then making my input the active element. I removed that piece of code and problem solved. Thanks.